# Coordinate values are out of range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY type

Tags: postgis, srid, osm2pgsql

After import some data from OSM file into Postgre, the coordinates numbers are too big and having trouble to cast to Geography:

```
Coordinate values are out of range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY type
```

In my table:

```
select ST_AsText( the_geom )  from routes limit 4

"LINESTRING(-4902130.86 -2265840.91,-4902083.04 -2265907.16)"
"LINESTRING(-4903296.22 -2266295.18,-4903363.69 -2266333.39)"
"LINESTRING(-5705594.67 -3518944.1,-5705523.22 -3518937.37)"
"LINESTRING(-5484056.84 -1884629.16,-5484093.47 -1884510.24)"
```

I think the numbers should be between (-90 / 90, -180 / 180) ...

Info:

1: select ST_SRID( the_geom )  returns 900913 for all lines.

2: select UpdateGeometrySRID('public', 'routes', 'the_geom', 4326) does not converts the numbers, but SRID now shows 4326.

Comment: 900913 is google web Mercator aux.. 900913 is outdated epsg code should be now EPSG:3857 -- WGS84 Web Mercator (Auxiliary Sphere) But that is in meters. and won't work for geography type. simply changing the srid won't do either. If someone doesn't post something soon I will try to help. this is the limit of my capability now.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But .... why do UpdateGeometrySRID not changes the coordinates? By the way, in other table the SRID shows 0 (zero) and it's working perfectly (for points)...

Comment: Because it only changes the information about SRID use `ST_Transform`.

Comment: YOU SAVE THE DAY !
`ALTER TABLE routes ADD temp geometry;

select UpdateGeometrySRID('public', 'routes', 'temp', 4326) ;

update routes set temp = ST_Transform(the_geom,4326);

select UpdateGeometrySRID('public', 'routes', 'the_geom', 4326) ;

update routes set the_geom = temp;

alter table routes drop column temp;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @Jakub Kania tip :

```
ALTER TABLE routes ADD temp geometry;
select UpdateGeometrySRID('public', 'routes', 'temp', 4326) ;
update routes set temp = ST_Transform(the_geom,4326);
select UpdateGeometrySRID('public', 'routes', 'the_geom', 4326) ;
update routes set the_geom = temp;
alter table routes drop column temp;
```

Comment: I can't change the_geom to 4326 before transform. ST_transform needs this information to make the magic, so I need the temp column.