# Distance between Paris and San Francisco with PostGis (out of range coordinates?)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geodjango, django

```
SELECT ST_Distance(gg1, gg2) As spheroid_dist, ST_Distance(gg1, gg2, false) As sphere_dist
FROM (SELECT
    ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(37 -122)') As gg1,
    ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(48 2)') As gg2
    ) As foo  ;
```

--> `ERROR:  Coordinate values are out of range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY type`

I understand those points are pretty distant (San Franciso vs Paris, France), but  how can I get the distance calculated between those two?

Comment: On my PostgreSQL 9.3, PostGIS 2.1.1 system I instead get `NOTICE:  Coordinate values were coerced into range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY`.

Comment: Did you search for the error? See http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/76092/12379, http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/24194/12379 .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you've got the wrong coordinate order. WKT for SRID 4326 is longitude then latitude (think Cartesian, it is X then Y). The error is telling you that -122 is not a valid latitude.

The geometry (or geography) needs to look like:

```
SELECT ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-122 37)')...

SELECT ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(2 48)')...
```

Answer (score 0):

By skimming the query, I guess that you missed to add "foo" :

```
SELECT ST_Distance(foo.gg1, foo.gg2) As spheroid_dist, ST_Distance(foo.gg1, foo.gg2, false) As sphere_dist
FROM (SELECT
    ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(37 -122)') As gg1,
    ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(48 2)') As gg2
    ) As foo  ;
```